# How can I make my <td> snap to the window?

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I'm using jQtouch and this JQTouch extension at http://code.google.com/p/jqextensions/.

I've my markup as

```
<div id="uiPage">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>UI/UX Design</h1>
        <a class="button back" href="#home">Back</a>
    </div>        
    <div class="horizontal-slide">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="slide-container current">
                        <img src="gallery/one.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slide-container">
                        <img src="gallery/two.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slide-container">
                        <img src="gallery/three.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slide-container">
                        <img src="gallery/four.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slide-container">
                        <img src="gallery/five.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slide-container">
                        <img src="gallery/six.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the `td` s to snap to the window just like the UI does as in the iPhone home screen.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make the `td`s snap to the window?

Comment: First of all, I would use <div> tags instead of TD's. Secondly there must be some kinda slide-container width you can multiply and from this calculate which xpos to snap-to-grid?

Comment: I was wondering the same but jQTouch uses table. It's in their code and it seems I've to use it to make the sliding work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [jQTouch Photo Gallery extension](http://code.google.com/p/jqextensions/wiki/JQTouchPhotoGallery)? Take a look at the [demo](http://samshull.com/jqtouch-r148/demos/main/) (esp "Photo Gallery" and "Photo Gallery 2").

A basic setup would look like this:

```
jQT.generateGallery("pageID",
    [
    {src:"http://www.site.com/somepic.jpg"},
    {src:"pic1.jpg",caption:"Test Image 1"}
    ],
    {
       hideToolbars: function() { }
    }
);
```

**EDIT:**

To show toolbars, it can be done as well. Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/aqito4/7

Simply disable the `hideToolbars` option, see modified code above.

Comment: I want the swipe to be active only on a `<div>` so that when the images are slided, only the images are slided while the toolbar and other elements stays

Comment: That is doable via an option `hideToolbars`, see modifications.